# Why does my sql generate weird naming in Rails?

Tags: sql

This query generates some strange sql and I don't understand where the weird table name comes from:

`order.apples.joins(:apple_trees).to sql`

results in:

```
SELECT "apples".* FROM "apples" INNER JOIN "apple_trees" "apple_trees_trees" ON "apple_trees_trees"."apple_id" = "apple"."id" INNER JOIN "apple_trees" ON "apples"."id" = "apple_trees"."apple_id" WHERE "apple_trees"."tree_id" = $1  [["tree_id", 393]]
```

I’m confused about this part:

```
INNER JOIN "apple_trees" "apple_trees_trees" ON "apple_trees_trees"."apple_id" = "apple"."id"
```

what is that apple_trees_trees part all about? I only have an apples table and an apple_trees table. Why does this sql generated have an extra `trees` attached to the table name?

Comment: `apple_trees_trees` is an alias in the SQL since you have a self-join it has to assign some new name to the second `apple_trees` table

Comment: Looks like it's just an alias. As to why? Not sure.

Comment: Is this valid SQL even?  What is `"apple"."id"` here?  You don't have an `"apple"` table in the query.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alias.  Possibly easier to see it this way. Not sure what generated it. It's possible someone wrote it this way. I highly doubt this was auto generated.

```
  INNER JOIN "apple_trees" AS ["apple_trees_trees"] 

   --Using the alias name here.
  ON  "apple_trees_trees"."apple_id" =  "apple"."id"
```

However, I could be wrong. Possibly there some auto naming generation for RAILS that auto apply table names to avoid duplication.